# Percentage of helmet owners in 15th century Europe

Tags: middle-ages, europe, armour, statistics

There already is a similar [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/35584/19711), but it has been closed as unclear. I will attempt to post a clear question instead.

- Time : 15th century
- Country: medieval Europe excluding Eastern Roman
  Empire, feel free to choose a country you can get data on.
- Setting: Urban, Peacetime

Background: in the 15th century, as argued in [this video](https://youtu.be/hV-tnlH3ffw), the [brigandine armour](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigandine) accompanied by helmet, mail and gambeson was already available to common soldiers or retinues. I am curious about the urban population and want to know what armour they possessed. To ask about chainmail might be a problem, because there are so many different pieces and we might get caught up in distinctions between hauberks and haubergeons. On the other hand, the helmet is perhaps the most indispensable piece of armour. To make it as definite as possible, I will ask:

> What percentage of the urban 15th century population in Europe (see above about countries) owned any kind of helmet?

Comment: I would say almost none, as armor was expensive and completely useless for the civilian population. Why would a civilian wear or  want to wear a helmet?

Comment: @Jos if no need arose to defend themselves against pointy things, you are obviously right. For nobles we know that they duelled. Also wars were not uncommon. If I would expect to fight within the next 30 years, I would certainly get myself a helmet.

Comment: An interesting question. It's often said, if one had any piece of armour, it would be a helmet. But I can't imagine someone owning a helmet just in case he might go to war at some point. Also you likely need to define helmet a bit clearer. Do you mean a steel helmet? A mail coif? A simple padded coif? Getting something protective to wear on the head such as a padded coif wouldn't be hard to procure, when you are called to war.

Comment: @Dulkan good point! I mean a solid helmet

Comment: you have to realize that very few people owned bicycles in the middle ages so there was very little demand for helmets.